# how to avoid URL encoding with ui-sref

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I've a link like this:

```
<a ui-sref="someState(Param:'مثال')"> A localized param </a>
```

when compiling the Angular-ui-router, generates a `href` like this :

```
<a href="#!/Procuts/%D8%B2%DB%8C%D8%B1%20%D8%B2%D8%A7%D9%86%D9%88"> A localized param </a>
```

how can I avoid this?

**what i have tried:**
creating a new type using `$urlMatcherFactoryProvider`

```
$urlMatcherFactoryProvider.type('decoded', {
    encode: function (item) {
        return decodeURIComponent(item) // i put this to decode personally
    },
    decode: function (item) {
        return decodeURIComponent(item);
    },
    is: function (item) {
        return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this actually happens inside 'angular' not 'ngRoute' , angular forces encoding all urls using `encodeURICompenent`, 
so you need to change `encodeUriQuery` inside angular.js so it would pass arabic characters without encoding

```
function encodeUriQuery(val, pctEncodeSpaces) {
  var r = /[\u0600-\u06ff]|[\u0750-\u077f]|[\ufb50-\ufc3f]|[\ufe70-\ufefc]/;
  if(r.test(val)){
    return val.replace(/\s/g,'-');
  }else{  
  return encodeURIComponent(val).
             replace(/%40/gi, '@').
             replace(/%3A/gi, ':').
             replace(/%24/g, '$').
             replace(/%2C/gi, ',').
             replace(/%3B/gi, ';').
             replace(/%20/g, (pctEncodeSpaces ? '%20' : '+'));
  }
}
```

if you're using minified version or don't want to bother looking into code here is a monkey patch you can copy and paste this anywhere in your code

```
window.encode = window.encodeURIComponent;
window.encodeURIComponent = function(val){return /[\u0600-\u06ff]|[\u0750-\u077f]|[\ufb50-\ufc3f]|[\ufe70-\ufefc]/.test(val) ? val.replace(/\s/g,'-') : window.encode(val)};
```

notice that part `replace(/\s/g,'-')` it replaces whitespaces with a dash because in angular it causes some issue to have whitespace in the url

Comment: thanks, REALLY THANKS! it's amazing how did you find that? I plowed the `ng-route`.

Answer (score 1):

the solution it's very simple actually
you can use javaScript `decodeURIComponent()` function on `$scope.item.title` for me it's worked like charm .

in controller use it like

```
$state.go("single-page", { contentType: "portfolio", date: "139411", title: decodeURIComponent("اولین-نمونه-کار-تست") });
```

in inspect you see something like :
    [image]
 its better for google seo ، google understood farsi better that way

but when you click on the link in url place you see this
[image]

Comment: could you please give us a sample